# Why isn't my wildcard + think + condition detected?

Tags: chatbot, aiml

I'm new to aiml and I'm trying to figure out why this isn't being detected. This is basically the example from docs modified with a wildcard.

```
   <category>
  <pattern>You want to buy some *</pattern>
  <template>
    <think><set name = "product"><star index="1"/></set></think>
     <condition name = "product" value = "deathsticksss">
         You don't want to sell me <star index="1"/>...you want to go home and rethink your life
     </condition>
  </template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `</category>` at the end of your category.